# django - installed apps - Error: No module named apps.finance

Tags: python, django

I wanted to change directory of where are my apps.
my django project is in this directory:

```
'/home/user/djcode/dev/myproject'
```

When I started this project, my apps where in this directory:

```
'/home/user/djcode/dev/myproject'
```

Aslo in settings.py I added this line (in INSTALLED_APPS):

```
'finance',
```

And everything worked.

Later I wanted to change my apps directory so I moved my apps to:

```
'/home/user/djcode/dev/myproject/myproject/apps'
```

And in settings.py I changed 'finance' into this line (in INSTALLED_APPS):

```
'myproject.apps.finance'
```

And when I ran python manage.py runserver command, I got this error:

```
Error: No module named apps.finance
```

I know I can just add path directly to where my apps are, so I think it would solve it. But isn't there a way to specify this path without adding it in .pth file?

What I mean is if python knows `/home/user/djcode/dev/myproject` path why it does not find `/home/user/djcode/dev/myproject/myproject/apps`?

Maybe I just wrongly specified in installed_apps?

Also I use virtualenv with this project, so django is installed using virtualenv. But I think it's not related, because it finds where my project is, but can't find apps if they are in lower directory lelvels.

Comment: Or it could be a circular import? Or you might not have a `__init__.py in the `apps` directory

Comment: Oh.. How could I forgot about `__init__.py`.. Thats it. Thank you very much. Now it works:)

Comment: @aychedee You can post it as answer and I will accept it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or it could be a circular import? Or you might not have a **init**.py in the apps` directory?